# JavaScript - sessionStorage how to store text area values?

Tags: javascript, html

On my web form I'm using the `sessionStorage` feature from HTML5 to store values from the form and then to present them on the Thank You page as sort of a confirmation receipt of their enquiry.

I have managed to store the values from every input type except for the `<textarea>` element.

I have tried:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Special", document.getElementsByName("specialInstructions").value);
```

but this doesn't get the value of the data typed in to the text area.

Here is the code for the `<textarea>` excluding `<form>` tags:

```
<textarea name="specialInstructions" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Here is the code I have been using for the other form elements:

```
if (!rephonenumber.test(document.bookingsform.phonenumber.value)) {
        document.bookingsform.phonenumber.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById("phonenumberwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid phone number.";
        document.bookingsform.phonenumber.title = "Please enter a phone number.";
        document.getElementById("phonenumberwarn").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.bookingsform.phonenumber.style.border = "1px inset #EBE9ED";
        document.bookingsform.phonenumber.style.borderRadius = "2px";
        document.getElementById("phonenumberwarn").style.display = "none";
        sessionStorage.setItem("Phone Number", document.bookingsform.phonenumber.value);
    }
```

Why doesn't this syntax work for text areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the exact element that you want the value from, since`document.getElementsByName` returns an array:

```
document.getElementsByName('name')[0]
document.getElementsByName('name')[1]
document.getElementsByName('name')[2]
...
```

you need to get the value with a position, try:

```
document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
```

you can use by id:

```
document.getElementById('name').value
```

Comment: Thanks all, I will use `getElementsByName` more appropriately next time. I used the `getElementById` method.

Answer (score 1):

By this function `document.getElementsByName` you will get the array of matching elements.

So for access first element of array and store it into localStorage, you could do something like this.

`sessionStorage.setItem("Special", document.getElementsByName("specialInstructions")[0].value);`

Here you can get the more information about [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

Answer (score 1):

The call to `document.getElementsByName()` returns a list of elements, not a single one. If you only have one `<textarea>` you can use `document.getElementsByName()[0].value`. Otherwise, you'll need to iterate through them.